# Passing Array with AJAX to PHP file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I should pass to a PHP file an array and a variable with AJAX.

If I try to pass only the variable, everything works fine, but if I try to pass also the array or only the array, I get some problems.

Here is my code:

```
function myfunction()
 {  
     var someObj={};
     someObj.SpecificGranted=[];

    xmlHttp.open('POST', "file.php", true);    
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
        { 
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) 
            {
            data: {
                    myvar : <?php echo $myvar;?>,
                    myarray:someObj.SpecificGranted;
                }            
             }
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    xmlHttp.send("myvar=<?php echo $myvar;?>"+myarray);
  }
}
```

And I would also ask how to retrieve the array in the PHP file... because 
  I'm not sure that `$_POST['myarray']` is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things one is `json stringify` the array variable and do `json_decode` in php to get the array back.

```
myarray: JSON.stringify(someObj.SpecificGranted);
```

OR if it is a simple array you can directly send it to php by

```
myarray[]: someObj.SpecificGranted;
```

Note the `[] in myarray`. You can get it in php using `$_POST['myarray[]']`.

Comment: I tried to put alert("hello"); after data {....}. It works if inside data there isn't  myarray[]: someObj.SpecificGranted;  but if I add it
alert isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in `jQuery`):

```
function myfunction() {
    var someObj = {};
    someObj.SpecificGranted = ['one', 'two'];
    $.get('file.php', {myvar: '123', myarray: someObj.SpecificGranted}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
myfunction();
```